# Создание новой таблицы и отправление на почту в SQL Server

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, select

Помогите с заданием. Мне нужно, что бы В SQL Server каждую ночь в 3 утра создавалась новая таблица на основе первой со всеми минусовыми значениями. И отправляла новую таблицу письмом к конкретному пользователю.

```
'''CREATE tabel2 AS
SELECT * FROM tabel1 WHERE account < 0 ;
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job  
@tabel2 = N'NightlyJobs' ;
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver  
@tabel2 = N'NightlyJobs Sales Data Backup',
@server = 'MyPC\data;   -- Default is LOCAL
GO'''
```

Comment: С чем именно возникла проблема? Создание таблицы? заполнение её данными? отправка? или вообще - запуск SSMS?

Comment: проблема с отправкой пользователю. понимаю, как сохранить на сервере, но не отправить

Comment: [Хранимая процедура sp_send_dbmail (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Спасибо! А как сделать, чтобы таблица создавалась именно в 3:00? У меня пока она создается просто каждую ночь

Comment: [sp_add_schedule (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-add-schedule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) с **правильными** параметрами. `@freq_type = 4, @freq_interval = 1, @active_start_time = 30000`.